# Find $a$ and $b$ such that $|ax+by|+|bx+ay|=|x|+|y|$ holds for any $x,y$; Same problem with [...] instead of |...|.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Found these 2 problems in an old notebook of mine . Tried to solve them , but i'm stuck on both of them. They both require me to find a and b real numbers for which the equation is true no matter what value x and y take (x,y real numbers too)

1.) $|ax+by|+|bx+ay|=|x|+|y|$

2.) $[ax+by]+[bx+ay]=[x]+[y]$

Note : [] refers to the integer part .

Comment: $a=0$, $b=1$ or viceversa, works

Comment: Thanks . Can you elaborate on how you got to that result , please ?

Comment: Ellaborate? just subsuititute. The problem is... Are there MORE solutions?

Comment: Yeah , that was my problem . Figured out that 0 and 1 would be one of the answers , but i didnt know how i was supposed to mathematicaly get there to them ( i mean what properties , theorems etc . i apply to get there  )

Comment: A standard way to approach these is to substitute values of $x$ and $y$, and see what conditions $a,b$ must satisfy.

Answer (score 2):

For the second problem.

For $y=0$ we have $[ax]+[bx]=[x]$.

For $x=y$ we have $[ax+bx]+[bx+ax] = [x]+[x]$, so $[(a+b)x]=[x]$.

In particular, for $x=1$ we have $[a+b] = 1$.

If $a+b \notin \mathbb Z$, write $a+b = [a+b] + \epsilon$.

Then for $N\in\mathbb N$ and $N > \frac 1 \epsilon$, $[N]=[(a+b)N] = [[a+b]N+\epsilon N]\ge N + 1$, a contradiction.

This gives $a+b=1$.

We have $[a]+[b]=[1]=1=a+b$. Since $[a]\ge a$ and equality hold iff $a\in\mathbb Z$, we have $a,b \in\mathbb Z$.

WLOG suppose $a>b$ and $a \ne 1$. Then $a > 1$.

We once again have $[ax]+[(1-a)x] =[x]$.

Take $x = \frac1{2a}$. Then $RHS =0$. $LHS=[\frac12]+[\frac{1-a}{2a}]=0+(-1) = -1$, which is a contradiction.

Hence $a=1, b=0$. Without the WLOG, $a=0, b=1$ works as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem.

If $y=x=1$ then   $|a+b|=1$.
If $y=-x=1$ then  $|a-b|=1$.

Case 1: $a+b=1$ $\iff$ $b=1-a$. Then
$$1=|a-b|=|a-(1-a)|=|2a-1| \iff \begin{cases}2a-1=1&\iff a=1 \\ 2a-1=-1 &\iff a=0\end{cases}.$$

Case 2: $a+b=-1$ $\iff$ $-b=1+a$. Then
$$1=|a-b|=|2a+1|\iff \begin{cases}2a+1=1&\iff a=0\\ 2a+1=-1&\iff a=-1.\end{cases}$$

Finally. For $x=0,\, y=1$ you'll get  $|a|+|b|=1$.
If $a=\pm1$, then $1+|b|=1$, whence $b=0$.
If $a=0$, then $|b|=1$ and $b=\pm1$.

Now you can CHECK by hand that $a=0, b=\pm1$ and vice versa are solutions to your problem.

So they are the only solutions.